# .htaccess to pass parameters and remove the page name

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following folder structure in my website:

```
     example.com/
                reports/
                        causelist/
                                 final_causelist.php
```

I have a link / URL to the final_causelist.php page is as:

```
http://example.com/reports/causelist/final_causelist.php?wb_sno=23&dated=2020-10-26&j_names=Mr.+ABC
```

I want to access the page like the following:

```
http://example.com/23/2020-10-26/Mr.+ABC
```

For the above, I created ***.htaccess*** in the ***causelist*** folder with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /reports/causelist/
Options -Indexes

RewriteRule ^(\d+)/([a-z-]+)/(.+)/$ /final_causelist.php?wb_sno=$1&dated=$2&j_names=$3 [L,B]
```

But it does not show the page and complaint that the requesting page is not found on this server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is not matching `date` part correctly and you must remove leading `/` from target as you're using a `RewriteBase`.

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /reports/causelist/

RewriteRule ^(\d+)/([\d-]+)/(.+?)/?$ final_causelist.php?wb_sno=$1&dated=$2&j_names=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Your solution is working fine when i put the lines in the ***.htaccess*** file existed in the root directory of my website. But copy your code into another ***.htaccess*** and put it in the  ***example.com/reports/causelist/.htaccess*** then it still fail?

Comment: Above code should be placed in `reports/causelist/.htaccess` and I am assuming `final_causelist.php` exists in same `reports/causelist/` subdirectory. Make sure when you test it there is no other rule in `reports/causelist/.htaccess`

Comment: Yes as per your guidelines i have only two files therein ```reports/causelist/``` directory one is ```final_causelist.php``` while the second one is ```.htaccess``` file having only the code you suggested.

Comment: But I have another ```.htaccess``` file in my root directory which includes some other rules.

Comment: Are you sure you have remove `/` before `final_causelist.php` in rule?

Comment: Where should I do change in the code if I need to add 4th parameter?

Comment: may be this: `RewriteRule ^(\d+)/([\d-]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ final_causelist.php?wb_sno=$1&dated=$2&j_names=$3&fourth=$4 [L,QSA]`

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(\d+)/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/(.+?)/?$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /reports/causelist/final_causelist.php?wb_sno=%1&dated=%2&j_names=%3 [QSA,NE,NC,L]
```

Comment: Like the solution of @anubhava, Your solution is also working fine when i put the lines in the .htaccess file existed in the root directory of my website. But copy your code into another .htaccess and put it in the example.com/reports/causelist/.htaccess then it still fail?

Comment: @AbdulRahman, I believe anubhava sir answered your question in their answer's comment, please try that once, cheers.

Comment: You can remove `RewriteBase` directive since you're using absolute URI in target

Comment: @anubhava, thank you sir, I was about to ask you why it isn't working for OP cheers :)